# How to use global variable in react native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to get a string from the globalvari.js file in my codes and print it on the screen. How can I do?

```js
import {a} from '../../globalvari'

export default class App extends Component{

 render() {

  var fav = ["item", "kopla"];

   return (
     <View style={styles.MainContainer}>

         { fav.map((item, key)=>(
         <Text key={key} style={styles.TextStyle}> { item } </Text>)
         )}

         { a.map((item, key)=>(
         <Text key={key} style={styles.TextStyle}> { item } </Text>)
         )}


     </View>
   );
 }
}
```

globalvari.js:

```js
var a = ["harrik","hsc"];
```

Comment: did you export `a` from `globalvari.js:`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "export" anything you want to use in another file:

```
var a = ["harrick", "hsc"];
export a;

var b = 324;
export b;
```

Then:

```
import { a, b } from '.... ';
```

Comment: this writing worked.  var a = ["harrick", "hsc"];
export {a};

var b = 324;
export {b};

Comment: use export default a;